# How can I inflate the ListView object

Tags: android, android-widget

The ListView instance is a part of the Layout.

```
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
    />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/launch"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
               <ListView android:id="@+id/resultlist"
                         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                         android:footerDividersEnabled="true" >
               </ListView>                        
               <Button android:id="@+id/start"
                       android:text="Predict!"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               />
        </LinearLayout> 
        ...

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to inflate the element with id=resultlist. Of course, I have developed the special Adapter and Layout for the content string of the ListView. The code looks like

```
    ListView view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.resultlist);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(
         new MyItem(R.drawable.class_01, "AUTO", 1, 0.0f),
         new MyItem(R.drawable.class_02, "BUS", 2, 0.0f),
    );
    view.setAdapter(adapter);
    setContentView(view);
```

But it works wrong. I can't see anything on device. (I'm sure I must use anywhere here my xml layout for ListView string and LayoutInflater instance, but where???)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call "setContentView" on the entire activity layout somewhere?  If not, that would likely explain the problem.